# Hide autofill dropdown on click outside of form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, search, autofill

I made an autofill search where when you type into the form field, it'll populate a dropdown of results that are from an array.

The issue I'm having is that when you click outside of the dropdown, it disappears as it should, but when you start typing into the form field again, the dropdown won't show. I'm trying to use jQuery to achieve this:

This is to display the dropdown under the search field:

```
const input = document.querySelector('#FAVORITE_LOCATION');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions ul');
const country = ['USA', 'Canada'];

function search(str) {
    let results = [];
    const val = str.toLowerCase();

    for (i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
        if (country[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1) {
            results.push(country[i]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}

function searchHandler(e) {
    const inputVal = e.currentTarget.value;
    let results = [];
    if (inputVal.length > 0) {
        results = search(inputVal);
    }
    showSuggestions(results);
}

function showSuggestions(results) {

    suggestions.innerHTML = '';

    if (results.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            suggestions.innerHTML += `<li>${results[i]}</li>`;
        }
        suggestions.classList.add('has-suggestions');
    } else {
        results = [];
        suggestions.innerHTML = '';
        suggestions.classList.remove('has-suggestions');
    }
}

function useSuggestion(e) {
    input.value = e.target.innerText;
    input.focus();
    suggestions.innerHTML = '';
    suggestions.classList.remove('has-suggestions');
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', searchHandler);
suggestions.addEventListener('click', useSuggestion);
```

Below is where I'm trying to hide the autofill that gets populated:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
    var container = $("ul.has-suggestions");
    if (!container.is(event.target) &&            
        container.has(event.target).length === 0) 
    {
       container.hide();
    }else{
        container.show();
    }
});
```

Lastly, here's the CSS for the dropdown itself

```
.search-container {
  position: relative;
}

.search-container input,
.search-container .suggestions {
  width: 100%;
}
.search-container input {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.search-container .suggestions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
ul.has-suggestions {
  display: block;
}
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

ul.has-suggestions is set to display:block when the user starts to type into the form field, which then shows a populated dropdown. I tried to use an if/else statement and using .show(); but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a full example? What does your array look like? What is your css and html structure?

Comment: @AtlanteAvila I just updated my post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this to show and/or hide your autocomplete suggestions:

```
input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  $("ul.has-suggestions").hide();
})

input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  $("ul.has-suggestions").show();
})
```

edit: 
[codepen with example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOEGpL)

edit 2 with requested update;
[codepen with example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWMXOV)

This second codepen populates the form field with the clicked value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It works on web which is great, but it doesn't seem to work for mobile?

Comment: Also, for web, when you click on one of the autofill suggestions, the text doesn't appear in the form field.

Comment: It works for me (Android + Chrome mobile browser). For other mobile devices you might need to add the **touchleave** event to handle when the user clicks outside the area, just add it to the blur event listener (separated by a space between 'blur' and 'touchleave').

Comment: Yeah I think I just had my old code in there that was causing it to not work, but now the issue is that if you click on the autofill suggestion, it won't populate into the formfield. That's for both mobile and web.

Comment: @anbhd please see the updated answer with second codepen and accept the answer if it works for you.